# LAMP stack in Ubuntu

Tags: lamp

I would like to install a **LAMP stack in Ubuntu Server** and going to use `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`.

Prior to this I would like to ask what is the difference between using this method and between installing each element separately?
There are many guides which go the second way.

Also, is it possible to know which versions of PHP, MySQL and Apache are going to be installed without actually installing them? (using sudo apt-get install lamp-server^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. convenience/ease
2. use the "-s" (simulate) switch for apt-get

EDIT:

Occurs to me it might be more useful to look at the policies the dependencies.  Maybe:

```
apt-cache policy lamp-server^
```

Comment: The only difference is convenience? 100%?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  To see what gets installed try `tasksel --task-packages lamp-server` - the various by-hand guides might specify a different set or whatever, but basically the tasks are there for convenience and ease.  If you use them then you should (unless there are bugs somewhere) get a working LAMP stack.  Interesting that perl is included though, that's not traditionally in a LAMP stack, wonder what the rationale for that is?